# Is there a Move towards function in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to three.js. I was wondering if there is a function like move towards from unity in it? A function that we can use to move our object from it's current position to some Vector3. 
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, read about [ask] and [mcve]. And re-work your question.

Comment: `object.translateOnAxis( axis, distance )` will get you started.

Comment: @prisoner849 I edited my question after reading the terms. I hope this one is ok. Thanks.

Comment: @RafaySaleem The answer to your question as currently written is 'No'. You will need to show the code you have tried.

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for the help. I managed to solve it using object.translateOnAxis()

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to solve this.

Here it is for anyone else stuck on this.

But you have to make sure that the object is a child of a THREE.Group and you move the THREE.Group instead of the object because the function doesn't behave right if the object's rotation is changed.

```
var targetPosition = new THREE.Vector3(x,y,z);
var objectToMove;
var group = new THREE.Group();
group.add(objectToMove);
var targetNormalizedVector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
targetNormalizedVector.x = targetPosition.x - group.position.x;
targetNormalizedVector.y = targetPosition.y - group.position.y;
targetNormalizedVector.z = targetPosition.z - group.position.z;
targetNormalizedVector.normalize()
```

Then you can use this line anywhere to move the object towards the target position.

```
group.translateOnAxis(targetNormalizedVector,speed);
```

This will work similar to the Vector3.MoveTowards function in unity. Just make sure the rotation of the THREE.Group is always set to 0 on x,y and z.